# error while executing select query(ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [xtydty2ldi], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [])

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, database-administration, ora-00600

I am facing the following error while running this simple select query

```
select * from ERICSSON_EUTRAN.NB_EUCELLFDD_5
```

> ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [xtydty2ldi], [], [], [],
>   [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

If I run the same query with an additional condition, query runs fine.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to resolving an ORA-600 bug is to go to support.oracle.com, search for "ora-600 tool", enter the first argument ("xtydty2ldi"), then click "Look-up Error".

In this case the website has two possible causes for this error.  Read through the related documents and try the workarounds.  (I'd post some of the content here but the data on the website is not meant to be shared.)

If you don't have access to that site then talk to a DBA or someone at your organization that has access.  They should be able to add you easily.

Don't worry too much about solving the problem.  As long as you can avoid it or work around it consider yourself lucky.  Some people will tell you to always submit a service request for every ORA-0600 but that will usually just waste a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you receive an `ORA-00600` it indicates a bug in Oracle itself, and not in your code.   You should contact Oracle support.

You might be able to work around the bug by changing your query, but without knowing the exact details of the internals it is difficult to know if you have really avoided the bug or it might occur again.

You may also have a hardware problem.